# How can I update date from firebase database 2 times?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[real-time database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwdCq.jpg)

What is right way to update from 2 buttons each button change value  .

I create 2 buttons one to update child "type" to 1, second button update to 2

but when I run app and click on first button work well but when click on second button the type value keep change between 1 and 2 and not stop until close app

what is problem in my code ? thx in advance

```
 DatabaseReference table_user;
    FirebaseDatabase database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_main);

     database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     table_user = database.getReference("Users");

}


public void active_C_page(View view) {

    table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            table_user.child("20160877").child("type").setValue("2");
            Toast.makeText(AdminMainActivity.this, "done 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMainActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

}

public void create_V_page(View view) {

    table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            table_user.child("20160877").child("type").setValue("3");
            Toast.makeText(AdminMainActivity.this, "done 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminMainActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `addValueEventListener` , it will fire when you click button 1, when you press button 2 it wil lchange the value again and `table_user` will keep updating.

To solve it change `addValueEventListener` with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`